# Same echo whether variable is empty or not

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have queries that stores values into variables. The variables are then used in a division and then in an echo. But the thing is that the selected value from the database sometime has a value and sometimes it doesn't exist because nothing is in the database. When there always is values in the database, I don't get error message, but I do get when there is no value.

Then I get this error:

> Warning: Division by zero in
>   D:\home\site\wwwroot\devlopment\respondents2.php on line 104

Line 104 is `$result00= round($sum/$total*100);`

This is my code

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT rid, pid, firstname, lastname, email FROM temp_members_db WHERE pid='$pid1' ");
echo "<table><tr><th>Namn</th><th>E-mail</th><th>Resultat</th><th>Ta bort kandidat</th></tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$count= "SELECT COUNT(qid) AS 'Total' FROM result WHERE rid=".$row['rid']."";
$result01 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $count); 
$resultArr01 = mysqli_fetch_array($result01);
$total= $resultArr01[0]*10;

$pointsummary= "SELECT SUM(points) AS 'Summary' FROM result WHERE rid=".$row['rid']."";
$result02 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $pointsummary);
$resultArr02 = mysqli_fetch_array($result02);

$sum= $resultArr02[0];
$result00= round($sum/$total*100);
$_SESSION['res'] = $row['rid'];

echo "<tr><td><strong>
<form action='respondent2.php' method='GET'>
 <input type='hidden' name='rid' value='".$row['rid']."'>
 <input type='hidden' name='firstname' value='".$row['firstname']."'> 
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='".$row['firstname']." ".$row['lastname']."'>

 </form>
 </strong></td> 
 <td>".$row['email']."</td> 
 <td><strong>".$result00."%</strong></td>   
</td></tr>"; }
```

I suppose that I maybe should try to put an "if empty statement" but when I tried I didn't fix it and got a blank page. I want to echo the same since `$result00` sometimes can have a value and sometimes not. I just want to get rid of the error message without any `error_reporting(0);`.

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump($total);` and tell us what happens?

Comment: @ Added that efter the 104 line. Got this: int(50) Warning: Division by zero in D:\home\site\wwwroot\devlopment\respondents2.php on line 104 int(0)

Comment: After your screenshot, as you can see, there's a `0%`... You can't divide by zero, so add a check that says `$result00 = ($total != 0 ? round($sum/$total*100) : 0);`, this will allow you to calculate percentage if the value is not 0, and if it is 0, you just display the number 0.

Comment: @Qirel It worked! Many thanks!!

Comment: You dont need 2 queries for that, you could use aggregate function `AVG()` and `Group By`. Its much easier. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need for this to work is to check if your variable is zero or not. If it is, you can just display zero directly instead of calculating it (resulting in a *Division by zero* warning).

A simple ternary-operator would do the trick

```
$result00 = ($total != 0 ? round($sum/$total*100) : 0);
```

You should do this for all results that *may* contain zero.

Take a read under "Ternary Operators" in the below link to read more on how these work.

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 2):

You should do it like this

```
$result00 = 
($total != 0 ? round($total*100/$sum) : 0);
```